# Backbone model.create not calling any callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have the following code to create a new model to a collection. The underlying datastore is a remote API:

```
        var postCreationStatus = this.model.create(newPostModel, {
            wait : true     // waits for server to respond with 200 before adding newly created model to collection
        }, {
            success : function(resp){
                console.log('success callback');
                console.log(resp);
            },
            error : function(err) {
                console.log('error callback');
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
```

The new model gets created, and I can confirm this from the database, but neither the success nor the error callbacks get called.

After the creation has been completed, I want to redirect the user. Redirecting prematurely kills the AJAX request, which is why it is important I use the success callback.

The server responds with a JSON response `{ id : 11 }` and an HTTP status of `200 OK`.

Comment: this title is incorrect, this question is not about collection.create

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking into the backbone code, I realized my call to the `create()` function was incorrect. The success and error callbacks needed to be within the object being passed in as the second argument, and not as a third argument. The changed, and working snippet is this:

```
var postCreationStatus = this.model.create(newPostModel, {
    wait : true,    // waits for server to respond with 200 before adding newly created model to collection

    success : function(resp){
        console.log('success callback');
        console.log(resp);
        that.redirectHomePage();
    },
    error : function(err) {
        console.log('error callback');
        // this error message for dev only
        alert('There was an error. See console for details');
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```